# React Router Redirect after Login not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

I'm developing a basic react application and included react-router. 
I have a simple authentication control with the Local Storage.

After a user inputs username and password and clicks login, I do an HTTP call and take response from the server with Axios. Then I set the localStorage 'user' item.

To protect a route I implemented the PrivateRoute component where I check if 'user' in localStorage is set.

I already tried to move set Local Storage inside then() in the Axios HTTP call but nothing changed.

Api CALL

```
  loginUser (username,password) {
    return HTTP.post('/login',  null, { params: {
      username,
      password
    }})


    Api.loginUser(username,password)
        .then( (response) => {
            console.log("Response DATA");
            Api.saveUserData(response.data);
            this.setState({ redirect: true });
        })
```

RENDER METHOD

```
if (this.state.redirect === true) {
    return <Redirect to='/home'/>;
}
```

APP COMPONENT

```
    class App extends Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }
```

PRIVATE ROUTE COMPONENT

```
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

      const isLoggedIn = AuthService.isAuthenticated();

      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={props =>
            isLoggedIn ? (
              <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
            )
          }
        />
      )
    }
```

The problems seem to be: the local storage is set after the redirect because is null. So I get blank page instead of loading the Home Component. If i refresh the page, the code works fine.

Comment: how are you accessing the localstorage?

Comment: localstorage.getItem()